# what are the alternative open source tools for PredictionIO?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

PredictionIO is good to be enough for content discovery and recommendation but it seems  it does not support classification. Then I should use a different tool then Prediction IO for my prediction server. Do you know good alternatives?

I know Google Prediction Server, Azure ML, BigML and looking for more alternatives to compare them.

Best :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on urgency I would recommend you to wait for the next release of PredictionIO ;)

It will have much better support for building custom engines (e.g., classification) and algorithms. You can subscribe to our newsletter at http://eepurl.com/u4OEH to catch the release announcement.

If you can't wait you can implement classification methods provided by some of the open source ML libraries such as Mahout, scikit-learn, Weka or the ML-as-a-service providers you mentioned.

Thomas

Comment: I would comment on this answer, @tstonez, but I can't.
On the next release of PredictionIO, how soon do you suppose will it come out?

Comment: This is possible as of recently released version 0.8.x, [see announcement](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/predictionio-user/ay_AxmekvLA/YdZk_ZaHlGYJ) on our user group. Though depending on use case you might want to wait for "engine template" for your use case (e.g., classification should be ready very soon you can [track issue/ticket on our public JIRA](https://predictionio.atlassian.net/browse/PDIO-352)).